# Why have we not observed neutrinoless double beta decay yet? What obstacles are there?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

Neutrinoless Double Beta Decay has been theorized by Majorana many, many years ago. Yet still, we have not detected this form of decay yet.

The Theory makes sense. What is preventing us from observing this? Are there any holes in the theory?

Comment: Regardless of any holes in the theory, it could still be the case that neutrinos simply aren't Majorana fermions. There are many mathematically consistent theories out there that don't explain reality, and it's not because something's wrong with their math. That said, the peak in the beta spectrum corresponding to neutrinoless double-beta decay is very tiny and hard to measure.

Comment: So ... to someone in low-background physics this is pretty obvious—it's simply a ***hard*** and *expensive* measurement—but it might help if you could say a little about what you do or do not know about how such measurements are attempted and why you think people should already have managed it. (I think COURE is nearly up to scale. They might be as close as *"a positive result this calendar year if they were really lucky, or a definitive negative one a few years from now"*.)

Comment: It's a very rare process. You need to have two weak decays happen at once, along with two neutrinos annihilating! Even observing just a normal double beta decay is hard.